# OpenGL doesn't seem to work in my Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, opengl

I used to create [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) applications in Windows XP.

When I moved to Ubuntu and set my development environment up, a `Segmentation fault` error always comes up everytime I compile and run my program. Then I tried to check the OpenGL status by running `glxinfo` through terminal (as suggested in a website), I got these errors:

```
root@ubuntu:/# glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
3 GLXFBConfigs:
   visual  x  bf lv rg d st colorbuffer ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
 id dep cl sp sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Segmentation fault
```

What should I do?

- Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx
- ATI Radeon 9550

I also have these packages installed:

- libgl1-mesa
- libgl1-mesa-glx
- libglu1-mesa

Any kind of help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What happens if you open `System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers`?

Comment: `No proprietary drivers are in use on this system.` =(

Comment: Can someone move this over to askubuntu.com?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the propreitory `fglrx` drivers. The [Ubuntu Community Documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) has details on how you can proceed with installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for errors (search for `(EE)`). If you've installed proprietary drivers before, you could have overwritten your GL libraries. For ATI/AMD cards, the proprietary driver is provided by the `fglrx` package, nvidia cards use `nvidia-current`. After uninstallation of these drivers, reinstall the mesa libraries:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Restart the X server (e.g. by rebooting) and these errors should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I have a Radeon 9550 on Ubuntu 10.04 as well without the proprietary drivers. Works just fine.

Your error messages suggest something is wrong with your X configuration. Which is weird, since for me it worked out of the box.

What happens if you try to run glxinfo as a regular user rather than root?